# Accessing the nested Arrays using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xEPGL/)

I'm not able to access the array images in the nested collection. Why am I not able to see any output?

The model:

```
var obj = [{
    "id": "7",
    "date": "1 Jan",
    "images": ["507f42c682882", "507e24b47ffdb", "507e2aeca02d5", "507e2b19663a9"]
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "date": "1 Jan",
    "images": ["507f42c682882", "507e24b47ffdb", "507e2aeca02d5", "507e2b19663a9"]
}];
```

This is the HTMl with ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="img in item"> 
        <br /> 
        <li ng-repeat="img1 in img.images">{{img1}}</li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to repeat a list of `li` elements inside of a `li` element, which is invalid HTML. As such, angular will not render this.

Update your HTML to:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="img in item"> 
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="img1 in img.images">{{img1}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Of course if u didn't want nested uls you are screwed

Comment: You'll need to find another approach if you want to render a flat list, that's true. Either by changing your HTML structure or by flattening the input array